# How to save a multiline output of sed command into array?

Tags: regex, arrays, bash, variables, sed

With this content in input.txt:

```
***** START *****
Hello
Stackoverflow 
***** END *****

OMG

***START *****
How
Are you
***** END *****
```

With the following command I save the content between `START` and `END` in an array:

```
sed -n '/START/,/END/p' input.txt
```

Works ok, but if I try to save it in an array, does not works:

```
arr=( $(cat input.txt | sed -n '/START/,/END/p') )

for text in $arr; do
    echo '%%%%%%%%'
    echo "$text"
    echo '%%%%%%%%'
    echo 
    echo 
done
```

It returns:

```
%%%%%%%%
*****
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%
START
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%
*****
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%
Hello
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%
Stackoverflow
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%
*****
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%
END
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%
*****
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%
***START
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%
*****
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%
Are
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%
you
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%
*****
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%
END
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%
*****
%%%%%%%%
```

And the desired output would be:

```
%%%%%%%%
***** START *****
Hello
Stackoverflow 
***** END *****
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%
***START *****
How
Are you
***** END *****
%%%%%%%%
```

What am I doing wrong? May be changing the value of IFS? Do you have any idea to do this? I'm so interested.

Comment: When I write a post and the comments let me see that this is not what I'm looking for, then I opt for delete the answer instead of modifying  becouse some users said that the question could not change to much. I apologize if it was bother you. Honestly, I thought it was the best way. Anyway, now I think the post is clear. Thanks! :)

Comment: No it doesn't bother me. I just found it a bit *strange* to see a thread disappear while being at the end of writing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do know this does not get data into an `array`, but maybe you do not need one?

```
awk '/START/{f=1;print "%%%%%%%%"} f; /END/{f=0;print "%%%%%%%%\n"}' file
%%%%%%%%
***** START *****
Hello
Stackoverflow
***** END *****
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%
***START *****
How
Are you
***** END *****
%%%%%%%%
```

---

And if you do not need the `START` `END` labels:

```
awk '/END/{f=0;print "%%%%%%%%\n"} f; /START/{f=1;print "%%%%%%%%"}' file
%%%%%%%%
Hello
Stackoverflow
%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%
How
Are you
%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Thanks Could you explain what `f` does un the awk?

Comment: @JohnDoe It is a variable used as a flag. Eks the `f;` will when `f` is `1`or any number except `0` do default action, in this case print the line.  So setting `f=0` or `f=1` controls when to print or not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can store a multi-multi lines in `bash` arrays as single array element (or at least I don't know a way of doing so). You can do test for `START` and `END` patterns and print accordingly:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'

arr=( $(sed -n '/START/,/END/p' file) )

for text in "${arr[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$text" =~ START ]]; then
        echo '%%%%%%%%'
        echo "$text"
    elif [[ "$text" =~ END ]]; then
        echo "$text"
        echo '%%%%%%%%'
    else
        echo "$text"
    fi
done
```

**Output**

```
%%%%%%%%
***** START *****
Hello
Stackoverflow 
***** END *****
%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%
***START *****
How
Are you
***** END *****
%%%%%%%%
```